How to plot maps in Python in Mollweide projection with rotated coordinate grid?
In Python, I try to plot all-sky maps in Mollweide projection. I am looking to be able to show maps with arbitrarily rotated coordinates and coordinate grid. See the following generic grid image (generated in IDL) for illustration: the map center rotated first to -105 deg longitude, then to +35 deg in latitude, with the grid lines transformed accordingly.

[generic grid image]
Is there any way to realize this in Python?
I have tried using matplotlib.pyplot or the mpl_toolkits.Basemap package  or cartopy package.
While all of these offer plots in Mollweide projection, with specific tailored capabilities, none of them offer the tool to rotate the center of the Mollweide map away from the equatorial plane.

Welcome to stackoverflow, Any feedback on my answer? If it answers your question, just click to accept it. And you will get some reputation points.

You can use cartopy to plot such projections. Here is a code that can be used as a starting point.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

# Target case
pole_lat = 35
pole_lon = 0
cent_lon = 180-105
rotated_pole2 = ccrs.RotatedPole( pole_latitude = pole_lat, 
                                pole_longitude = pole_lon,
                                central_rotated_longitude = cent_lon)
# Create plot figure and axes
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Mollweide())
ax.set_global()

# Plot the graticule
ax.gridlines(crs=rotated_pole2, draw_labels=False, 
             xlocs=range(-180,180,30), 
             ylocs=range(-90,90,30)) #draw_labels=True NOT allowed

# Plot some texts at various locations
lonlats = [ [0,0, '(0,0)'], [0,45, '(0,45)'], [0,90, '(0,90)'],
            [-105,0, '(-105,0)'], [-150,0, '(-150,0)'], [60,0, '(60,0)'], [90,0, '(90,0)']]
for ea in lonlats:
    ax.text(ea[0], ea[1], ea[2], fontsize=8, fontweight='ultralight', color="k", transform=rotated_pole2)

plt.show()


To make sure that the plot is correct, the coastlines are plotted on the projection. The result is:


This is an option to get there; however, Cartopy is very poorly documented imo, and it does not offer much flexibility in customizing the plot (axis labels, title, colormaps and colorbar with labels, etc.)
This is why I have been looking for a more accessible and potentially easier solution.
